# Python - Enter password when prompted

Tags: python, ssh, kivy, ssh-tunnel

I'm going to ssh to the server using python and kivy in order to make an ssh tunnel. What I've done is execute this command: `ssh -vND port user@my-server-ip`.

```
import os

connect_command = "ssh -vND port user@my-server-ip"
returned_value = os.system(connect_command)
password = "something-got-from-user-input"
```

It is connecting correctly but the problem is that I can't enter the password when `user@my-server-ip's password:` prompted.

What I have done for this, is:

```
text = "user@my-server-ip's password:"
if (returned_value.startswith(text)):
    os.system(password + "\n")
```

but it doesn't work.

So how can I enter the password I got from the user when it needs the password to be entered in order to connect?

Comment: `os.system` executes commands; it does not simulate you typing at the keyboard. Further, commands like `ssh` read passwords directly from the terminal, not from something standard input. If you want to automate an SSH connection, I strongly suggest setting up public-key authentication for the host. Then you won't need a password at all; you can configure `ssh` to retrieve your private key from disk with no user interaction.

Comment: Thank you! But I need to use a password as I have a specific issue.

Comment: Perhaps that's the issue you should be asking about.

Comment: At the very least, you might be able to use `sshpass` to feed a password to `ssh`, but you are creating opportunities to compromise the password by having it passed through Python to `sshpass` to `ssh`.

Comment: sshpass is not recognized in Windows. I want something that is available on any platform.

Comment: The other thing you might want to figure out is why the user can't type their password directly to `ssh`. That should be possible.

Comment: The user can, but I want to make it a program to do it to make it visual without any technical command. Doesn't `ssh` have some argument like --password=password to prevent the prompt? and use that password with one command.

Comment: `ssh` doesn't have a `--password` option because exposing the password on the command line would be a security risk. Don't try to interfere with `ssh`; if the user can see the prompt, let them type their password. If they user decides *they* want to use public-key authentication, they can do so and not see a prompt at all. In short, it's not your program's problem to "help" `ssh` authenticate. Just sit back and let `ssh`do its thing.

Comment: Does it have to use the standard library? If not, then try asyncssh.